# Google not indexing/updating rel="canonical" pages

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, google-search, canonical-url

I had same content with different links and I wanted to prioritize the indexing of different webpages.

For example `/A/1232` and `/A/1232/tum_bin_jiya_jay` represent same content but I wanted to give more priority to `/A/1232/tum_bin_jiya_jay` link over `/A/1232`.

So I put this canonical links in all pages from where I wanted to tell Google please give more preference to the link given in this page I used this in non-priority links and don't use any canonical in priority links.

In the head section of URL `/A/1232` I put below line so that Google can give more priority to below page but even after 4 days none of such pages are indexed by Google

```
  <link rel="canonical"  href="http://example.com/A/1232/tum_bin_jiya_jay" />
```

Can anyone suggest what should I do, I have submitted both links to Google webmaster and earlier links are already indexed so Google is not indexing `/A/1232/tum_bin_jiya_jay` link but Google Webmaster will give more priority to those links and will index but I don't know why its not indexing.

If i remove earlier links from Google webmaster sitemap than what is the chances of including this type of links.which is advisable.

Comment: Your implementation sounds correct, but as bybe says, you need to give it some time.  I'd suggest at least two weeks.

Answer (score 2):

Use: `<link rel="canonical"  href="http://aexample.com/A/1232/tum_bin_jiya_jay" />` On (`/A/1232/tum_bin_jiya_jay`

And use /A/1232 on `<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow">` if you do not want duplicate content ending up in the index, the follow means that Google will pass juice if someone links to it.

You major problem here is that you've only waited 4 days, changes to pages can take days, weeks and even months. If you have done the canonical links correctly then its just a waiting game, removing the URLS will not increase the speed of Google.

**Additionally**

- Resubmitting a site map does not increase index time.
- Removing URLs does not increase index time.
- Submitting to URLS to Google does not always speed up index time.

The more often you update your site in 'CONTENT' the more often they will return to your site and the chances they will freshen their index. Take this site as a prime example, most often new questions end up in the index within 5mins while 'NORMAL' sites can take days, weeks and even months if you do not keep your site constantly fresh.

Comment: as per google webmaster guidelines <link rel="canonical" href="http://aexample.com/A/1232/tum_bin_jiya_jay" /> should be placed only on page where the priority is less and should not be placed on high priority pages here is link  http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394

Comment: Not true at all and it has nothing to do with setting a high priority. Canonical pages get index, duplicate pages do not get indexed. You can use rel canonical on both pages as long as it points to your master page, or just use noindex on the page that is duplicate. The problem here is that you've only waited 4 days, as stated.

Comment: Added the solution with noindex, of course its not required but there's little point in having both pages indexing, crawled - if they are the same - but again... your problem is you've only waited 4 days..

Comment: "...it has nothing to do with setting a high priority." - The CLE is a _suggestion_ to search engines/google that the specified (canonical) URL is the preferred URL when serving similar content. So in this sense you are setting a _priority_. You are prioritising the canonical URL over the non-canonical URL - which Google might choose to ignore. Google themselves use the word "prioritize" in their example.

Comment: True but you can force Google's hand using `content="noindex,follow"` on the duplicate, but then what would be the point of using canonical :P

Comment: Regarding **noindex**, Google states: "We don't recommend using noindex to prevent selection of a canonical page within a single site, because it will completely block the page from Search. rel="canonical" link annotations are the preferred solution."